# How to simplify the method that does not use the if statement

Tags: android, if-statement

How to  simplify the method that does not use the if statement and to reduce the number of lines of my code. Here is how i wrote:

```
    private void RemoveImg() {
        while (true) {
            rel_with_images.getChildCount();

            if ((number_of_Image== 5) {
                rel_with_images.removeViewAt(number_of_Image- 1);
                sp_1 = sp11.play(sp_1 , 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                inta11 = sp11.play(intaa, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                CheckVibrate();
                MainAct c5 = MainAct .this;
                c5.number_of_Image = (-1 + c5.number_of_Image);
                break;
            }
            if ((number_of_Image== 4) {
                rel_with_images.removeViewAt(number_of_Image- 1);
                sp_1 = sp11.play(sp_1 , 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                inta11 = sp11.play(intaa, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                CheckVibrate();
                MainAct c5 = MainAct .this;
                c5.number_of_Image = (-1 + c5.number_of_Image);
                break;
            }
            if ((number_of_Image== 3 ) {
                rel_with_images.removeViewAt(number_of_Image- 1);
                sp_1 = sp11.play(sp_1 , 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                inta11 = sp11.play(intaa, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                CheckVibrate();
                MainAct c5 = MainAct .this;
                c5.number_of_Image = (-1 + c5.number_of_Image);
                break;
            }
            if ((number_of_Image== 2 ) {
                rel_with_images.removeViewAt(number_of_Image- 1);
                sp_1 = sp11.play(sp_1 , 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                inta11 = sp11.play(intaa, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                CheckVibrate();
                MainAct c5 = MainAct .this;
                c5.number_of_Image = (-1 + c5.number_of_Image);
                break;
            }
            if ((number_of_Image== 1) {
                rel_with_images.removeViewAt(number_of_Image- 1);
                sp_1 = sp11.play(sp_1 , 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                inta11 = sp11.play(intaa, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
                CheckVibrate();
                MainAct c5 = MainAct .this;
                c5.number_of_Image = (-1 + c5.number_of_Image);
                break;
            }
       }
}
```

number_of_Image is Integer which counts the number of images in relative layout rel_with_images. The code is a little big when there are more than 30 pictures in layout. Does anyone know a solution? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the if statement to start with? The code in each if statement is the same as far as I could tell. Pointless if statement (unless I read it wrong), just remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void removeAllImages() {
    int numberOfImages = rel_with_images.getChildCount();

    while (numberOfImages > 0) {
        removeImageAt(number_of_Image-1)
        numberOfImages = rel_with_images.getChildCount();
    }
}

private void removeImageAt(int position) {
    rel_with_images.removeViewAt(position);
    sp_1 = sp11.play(sp_1 , 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
    inta11 = sp11.play(intaa, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
    CheckVibrate();
    MainAct c5 = MainAct .this;
    c5.number_of_Image--;
}
```

Comment: note, I have little confidence that the content of `removeImageAt(int)` will work/compile - it's just a refactoring of what you have in your original question.

Comment: Thank you for responding. your code work i just tested it but remove all views from layout. the method RemoveImg remove just one image per user click.

Comment: i fixed it now work. i put break in  while (numberOfImages > 0) {
        removeImageAt(number_of_Image-1)
        numberOfImages = rel_with_images.getChildCount();
        break;
    }


Thank you

Comment: ah yeah sorry, I missed the `break` in your code - my example intentionally got rid of all views as I thought that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: Np :) i learned alot from this post. Thanks